# Definition of n independent event and example

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given a finite set of events $A_1,\dots,A_n$, the events are said to be independent if and only if **for any** subset of indices $I$ we have:
$$\mathrm{P}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i\right)=\prod_{i\in I} \mathrm{P}(A_i)$$

That means that if the condition holds for $ I=\lbrace 1,\dots, n \rbrace$ we are not sure that the events are independent because it could not hold for one of the subsets of I (for example for $I=\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace$).

Could anyone give me an example (or a reference) in which the condition
$$\mathrm{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathrm{P}(A_i)$$
holds but the events are not independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say our probability space $\Omega$ contains the sets $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$, and that $0 < P(A_1) < 1$, $P(A_3) = 0$ and $A_1 = A_2$. Then $P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3) = P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = 0$, but $P(A_1)P(A_2) = P(A_1)^2 \neq P(A_1) = P(A_1 \cap A_2)$.